# Visual Studio 2013, Firebird and Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I still cannot use EF with Firebird in VS2013 pro and Win7 pro !

Here's what I have done :

I have created a new class library for my dal project, and imported the ef6 and the firebird provider via nuget like said in this page http://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient-EF6/

Then I copied the fb provider to some place and use gacutil to register it into the cache:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil -i fibirdprovierpath
```

Please note that I used the gacutil from the netfx4.5.1 (don't know if it change something)

After that I grabbed the ddex dlls, put them somewhere, change the regfiles that came with (32/64), for the path and ran them.

I have also modified the `machine.config` (32/64) to reference the Firebird provider .

Now, I can add a Firebird connection without any problem in the servers window, I can even create a Winforms pp that uses a Firebird dataset, BUT when I want to add an `.edmx` model, the Firebird option is unavailable, I have only SQL Server.

Make sense to anyone please !!!

Comment: If this is EF6 then from EF point of view you should not GAC EF6 providers rather than you should add the provider to the project just by adding the NuGet package

Comment: sorry but cannot understand why, anyway this what i did,in my DAL project i have imported the ef6 and corresponding firebird provider, but still can't see th firebird option in the edmx wizard, again i can add fb databases in the servers panel or in winform datasets but not in edmx

Comment: Can you share your project or create a bug at https://entityframework.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create and attach your project (ideally the repro project should be as simple as it gets)?

Answer (score 0):

Is this not related to your problem?  http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-522

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. Use links to support your point or link to useful expansions on your answer. Consider what will happen if that link should change.

Answer (score 0):

i finally fugured out how to fix that !

with the registry files there is another subfolder named **withSDK** and it was empty,
so i searched for an older ddex files , edited the registry files that are located in that **withsdk** folder and voila !